# Crystal report shows only one page C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, crystal-reports

I'm using crystal reports in a C# Windows Form application to generate a report from a dataset, everything works fine but it only generates one page of the report for example if I have 20 rows in my dataset and the report page fits only 10 I will get the first ten and no other pages. How can I make a multiple page report what am I doing wrong ?
Here is code that I'm using:

```
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
      conn = dbclass.getconnection();
      conn.Open();
      // Create the command
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(scmd, conn);
      SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
      allcrsds ds = new allcrsds();

      adapter.Fill(ds, "allcars");
      adapter.Dispose();
      dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["allcars"].DefaultView;
      allrp.SetDataSource(ds);
      ds.Dispose();
      conn.Close();
```

[thats how i made the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvZHC.jpg)

[thats the report i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceqXy.jpg)

Comment: how many rows in dataset?

Comment: 19 rows but i see only 14 in the report

Comment: can you show preview of the report?

Comment: i added some screenshots to my question

Comment: There are two possibilties for this behaviour... you may be seeing the records in database and comparing to report, It can happend that in your query you are just retriving only 14 records and one more option is check `Record Selection Formula` of the crystal report if there is some condition there then also some records may get filtered and only few can be retrived and shown in report...Else I don't see any other possibility..

Comment: when i get the data i get all of it to the data grid view ...the problem is only in the report,i checked the record selection formula and it's empty

Comment: In that case you should be able to see another page with the remaining data...To the extent I know where can crystal hide the data until and unless you are supressing the data... check for any data supress conditions on detail section

Comment: still the same problem :( no supress conditions